# PhoneGap - Preventing Screen Orientation Changes

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I've used a plugin to try and lock the screen orientation within my PhoneGap app:

[cordova-plugin-screen-orientation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation)

Within my app page I have the following code extract:

```
// Once DOM is loaded...
$(document).on('pagecreate', function() {

window.screen.lockOrientation('portrait');                  // Seems to set variable but not LOCK screen?

var orient = screen.orientation;                            // Works
alert(orient);                                              // Works

window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){    // Works
    alert(screen.orientation); // e.g. portrait             // Works
});                                      

... Other code etc.
```

As you can see from the comments the plugin seems to be installed correctly as I am successfully calling portrait-primary, landscape-secondary etc. as I rotate my phone. The issue seems to be the function isn't LOCKING the screen?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to lock the orientation throughout your app ?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal - yes I am looking to lock throughout the app. As per the comment further down I have tried to do this avi the config.xml file but with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting this attribute in your `config.xml`.

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I have actually already got that within config.xml but it still won't lock orientation. Is this possibly to do with running the PhoneGap desktop and iOS app and not doing a full "build"? I've not built an app before so it could be a nuance of the PhoneGap environment.